# How/Can I specify the version of the SQL Server Native Client OLE DB (SQLNCLI) in the connection string

Tags: sql-server-2016, sqlclient

I know that using the OLEDB Driver (MSOLEDBSQL) I can specify this with the Driver keyword as [documented here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client/applications/using-connection-string-keywords-with-sql-server-native-client?view=sql-server-2016).

Can this be done with the SQLNCLI driver?

MY ISSUE:
I see on the target machine that both version 10 and 11 are installed and we are getting the following error, that I suspect is due an disabling of tls1.1.

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can't.
I had the v10 version of the SQLNCLI  driver uninstalled and everything seems to be working.